# Can't select "Nuget Packet Manager" in my Visual Studio 2015 Solution

Tags: django, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I'm building a basic Django Project in Visual Studio 2015 (Update 2). I have installed the Nuget extention. However, I can't select the "Manage Nuget Package for Solution...".
I've already spent hours on the web (and largely here) trying to figure out how to manage that... 
I'm not in debug mode...

I'm quite a newbie in Visual Studio, any help appreciated! Thanks,
Arnaud

Comment: Can you check tool->Extensions and updates and make sure NuGet package manager is installed in the list of installed extensions?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. Yes indeed, it's installed (I've already uninstalled it and reinstalled it, tried to redo it in admin mode, repaired Visual Studio...).

Comment: Does it show up when you create a wpf or a console project?